# Styling JFoenix Tabpane

Tags: javafx, jfoenix, javafx-css

[I am using JFoneix Library for creating a tabpane in javafx. Everything works fine however i am unable to remove the extended line connecting the tabs. How can i achieve that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxzjH.png)

Below Css has been used to design the tabpane

```
#testDatesTab .tab-selected-line {
    -fx-background-color: #0059A9;
}
#testDatesTab .headers-region {
    -fx-background-color: #F5F6F8;
}
#testDatesTab .tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
#testDatesTab .control-buttons-tab{
    -fx-background-color:white;
}
#testDatesTab .control-buttons-tab .tab-down-button{
    -fx-background-color: #0059A9 ;
}
#testDatesTab *.tab-header-area {
    
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using those style lines you should not have problems, maybe if you have something else in your css it is what is causing that problem, look I just made an example.
Add your full css.

[image]

Comment: In addition to above css i have added "-fx-border-color:white;" and  "-fx-border-width: 0 5 0 0" to individual tabs programatically.

Comment: that's the problem  "-fx-border-width: 0 5 0 0" right border width is 5 you need to set to 0 with that it will be solved

Comment: yes but what if want white border in between two tabs?